# My code doesn't work with std::map and sf::Vector2i

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, sfml, stdmap

I am trying to make a pathfinding system for the SFML, but I am stuck because of a compilation error. This error occurs when I try to add an element to my std::map . Here is the header code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <map>

class Node {
    public: 
        float cout_g, cout_h, cout_f;
        sf::Vector2i parent;
};

class Pathfinding
{
    public: 
        Pathfinding(sf::Vector2i);
        std::list<sf::Vector2i> searchPath(sf::Vector2i endpoint,sf::Vector2i startpoint);

    private: 
        std::map<sf::Vector2i,Node> closedList;
        std::map<sf::Vector2i,Node> openList;
};
```

And here is the source code:

```
#include "Pathfinding.h"

Pathfinding::Pathfinding(sf::Vector2i coords)
{
}

std::list<sf::Vector2i> Pathfinding::searchPath(sf::Vector2i endpoint, sf::Vector2i startpoint)
{
    Node startNode;
    startNode.parent.x = 0;
    startNode.parent.y = 0;
    openList[startpoint] = startNode;
    std::list<sf::Vector2i> list;
    return list;
}
```

And here is the game loop:

```
#include "Pathfinding.h"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"A* Test");
    Pathfinding pathfinder(sf::Vector2i(800,600));
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }
        std::list<sf::Vector2i> path = pathfinder.searchPath(sf::Vector2i(3,3),sf::Vector2i(45,55));
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code isn't functionnal at all, I reduced it to the minimum for the debugging.
I really don't understand the error code it is giving: http://pastebin.com/mBVALHML (I am posting it on Pastebin because it is really long). The only thing I understand in this error is the problem comes from this line:

```
openList[startpoint] = startNode;
```

I also tried to compile with SFML 2.1 and 2.2, but it didn't worked. So do you know why I am getting this error, and maybe how to fix it ? 
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sf::Vector2<T>` has no `operator<` but in order to use it as a key in a `std::map` it needs such an operator.
You somehow have two options, without the need to modify `Vector2.hpp`: One complex and one easy but not so wanted way.

**Easy**

Simply make the `map`s from a *fixed* size, e.g.

```
/*some function-head-thing*/(sf::Vector2u size)
{
    for(unsigned int y = 0U; y < size.y; ++y)
        for(unsigned int x = 0U; x < size.x; ++x)
            map[x + y * size.x] = /*some init value*/
}
```

In order to access the elements in the map you always need to know the size but it stays simple: `map[x + y * size.x]`.

**Complex**

As the `operator==` is defined for `sf::Vector2<T>` you simply need to add a `std::hash` specified for `sf::Vector2<T>` and then you can replace the map with an `std::unordered_map`.
Maybe something like this:

```
namespace std
{
    template <class T>
    struct hash<sf::Vector2<T>>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const sf::Vector2<T>& v) const
        {
            using std::hash;

            // Compute individual hash values for first
            // and second. Combine them using the Boost-func

            std::size_t tmp0 = hash<T>()(v.x);
            std::size_t tmp1 = hash<T>()(v.y);

            tmp0 ^= tmp1 + 0x9e3779b9 + (tmp0 << 6) + (tmp0 >> 2);
         }
    };
}
```

But be careful if you want to use sf::Vector2f! Better add a `static_assert` to restrict the usage of `T`, it should not be floating point as the `operator==` might not give expected results, no matter if fuzzy-compare or not.

**Otherwise**

Add some `operator<` in the `Vector2.hpp` and `Vector2.inl`, however you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D , I was really lost . I chose to use std::pair<int,int> instead of sf::Vector2i, because all I want from it is to store the position of a point. But you really helped me understand the problem in my code :)